# Impact Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I have been looking at a paper modelling velocities and accelerations for dropped objects, in this case a perfectly elastic collision for an object hitting the ground. Where $v_1$ is the impact velocity and $v_2$ is the velocity immediately after impact (i.e the rebound velocity), the velocity time graph can be modeled using the following equation:

[image: Velocity]

The differential should give acceleration, as shown here:

[image: Differential for Acceleration]

But...shouldn't the differential of Cos be -Sin? Should the equation not be "- $\pi/T$ Sin(...etc) have I missed something? When I graphed it as 'positive' Sin the acceleration-time graph comes out upside down.

Comment: $(\cos ax)'=-a\sin ax$, for sure.

Comment: Do you have citation for that stuff?

Comment: This is the document: https://www.endevco.com/contentStore/mktgContent/endevco/dlm_uploads/2019/02/TP321.pdf

Answer (score 0):

From your [reference](https://www.endevco.com/contentStore/mktgContent/endevco/dlm_uploads/2019/02/TP321.pdf), $\text{Fig.3}$, it can be seen that in fact $v(t)$ starts off negatively ($<0$). Which is as it should be because the vector points downward.

If so, then $\frac{\text{d}v(t)}{\text{d}t}$ must be positive because the derivative of a $\cos$ is a $-\sin$.

The acceleration vector points upward during the collision, so its scalar is positive.

Someone dropped a minus sign in the $v(t)$ expression.

Comment: so equation (8) should be negative Cos...?

Comment: Yes. Look at the $\vec{v}$ wrt the axis vector.

Comment: but this now just inverts the velocity time graph (example when v1= -1 and v2=1) and the acceleration time graph remains inverted as well if SIN remains positive in equation (10)

Comment: In Eq. 8 the $\cos$ must be negative, because indeed $v<0$, at least initially. Eq.10 then fits Fig.2 because $(\cos x)'=-\sin x$. Thus $a$ becomes positive as it should be.